# Can I change the color of my Mac OS X Terminal window depending on which server I am ssh-ed to?

Tags: macos, terminal

I'd like to have the background as black for server 'foo' but have the background be say gray  or blue for server 'bar'.

I am worried I'll run the wrong command on the wrong ec2 instance because all the pwds are `/home/ubuntu`! How is everyone else solving this?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but pretty close. See: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9740/can-i-tell-iterm-2-to-change-color-when-im-root

Comment: I want to do this too! In particular, I want the .login on each remote system to send the correct escape sequence to change the background colors. However, when I log out, I want the old colors restored...

Answer (score 2):

you can use a script to connect to your servers, which also changes the bg color of your terminal before it connects.

http://www.macosxhints.ch/index.php?page=2&hintid=1001

Comment: This is a dead link with a German popup.

Answer (score 2):

Use different bash scripts to launch each session and change the background color depending on the server.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404242/programmatically-launch-terminal-app-with-a-specified-command-and-custom-colors

Answer (score 1):

You may use [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com/) bookmarks, where you can customize each bookmark with its own settings!

Answer (score 0):

Further to the iTerm bookmarks that are in [@nuc's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/10211/237) where you have to create a profile for each machine and then make its script the ssh command.

iTerm also has some [shell integration](https://iterm2.com/documentation-shell-integration.html) which you can use to choose different iTerm profiles (these include colour schemes) depending on the machine name. Thus your terminal changes colour when you ssh into a machine which you can do at any time and not just at the start of a session as in the above case.